# Object from Array of Dictionaries into an Array

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, dictionary

If I have an array of dictionaries in my NSUserDefaults:

```
["name":"John", "birthplace":"New York"]
["name":"Eric", "birthplace":"London"]
["name":"Sven", "birthplace":"Stockholm"]
["name":"Pierre", "birthplace":"Paris"]
```

What is the simplest way to get all the names into an array like this

```
John, Eric, Sven , Pierre
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, you should get the array from user defaults in correct type which is `[[String: String]]`:

```
let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
if let peopleArray = defaults.arrayForKey("people") as? [[String: String]] {
  ...
}
```

Then you can use [`flatMap`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/dictionary/1687661-flatmap) *(or `map` if you are sure each dictionary has the key `name`)* to extract the names:

```
peopleArray.flatMap { $0["name"] }
```

Comment: updated question. how would I get this array out of NSUserDefaults?

Comment: yes, they are saved with something like defaults.setObject([["name":"John", "birthplace":"New York"],["name":"Eric", "birthplace":"London"]], forKey: "people")

Comment: If I do `var peopleArray = defaults.arrayForKey("people")` then the flatMap code produces `Cannot subscript a value of type '[AnyObject]' with an index of type 'String'` (Swift 2.x)